# A man for whom or A man in whose case

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

Which of the following sounds better in a formal manner?

1. A man for whom one year has not passed(elapsed) since he was graduated from the college.
2. A man in whose case one year has not passed(elapsed) since he was graduated from the college.

Any comments or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: We really need some more details of why you think either sentence is a problem, otherwise you are really just asking us to proofread.

Answer (score 1):

Neither sentence is good though both are grammatical. Being formal does not require writing like a poorly programmed robot.

> A man who graduated from college less than year ago

is more concise, more comprehensible, more natural, and every bit as formally correct as either proposed sentence.

Answer (score -1):

If being formal you should prefer,

> **A man for whom** one year has not passed(elapsed) since he was graduated
>   from the college.

Either **passed** or **elapsed** are equally 'formal,' but using the word '**passed**' would sound more natural to most English-speakers